# Multi-boot USB using Windows bootloader and UEFI, for WinPE 4.0 and Windows 8 installation

Tags: windows-8, usb, boot, secure-boot

I have a large USB drive that I would like to use to multi-boot several Windows products. The way my project seems to differ from every other thing I have found on Google is that I want it to work seamlessly with [Secure boot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#Secure_boot) enabled, and I'm not trying to boot Linux.

I have four items that I want to boot: Windows 8 x86 and x64 installation discs, and [WinPE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Preinstallation_Environment) 4.0 x86 and x64. Later, I might wish to add Windows 7 and WinPE 3.0, but that isn't necessary at this point.

The problem that I have is that I am unable to choose the item that I wish to boot, because there is no boot selection dialog that I can find anywhere. I am able to create the USB with multiple .wim files in the sources folder, and I have even been able to use [BCDEdit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709667%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) to modify BCD for multiple OS entries - but none of them ever show up!

How can I fix this problem? From a single USB drive, I wish to be able to install Windows 8 or boot from a PE.

Comment: The process works best if you already have Windows 7 installed and add the Windows 8 installation. This replaces the Windows 7 Boot Manager with the Windows 8 Boot Manager. This will allow you to simply add additional options to the bootable partitions. In the end you might have to use an alternative Boot Manager like Grub 2. **Windows 7 does not support Secure Boot.**  **If the boot options are not showing up you are not doing a required step to display those options for Windows 8 ( the process is slightly different then Windows 7 ).

Comment: This isn't for an installed OS, it's for USB boot installation and PE disks.

Comment: Considering my own advice has worked for me in the past it should work.

Comment: Well, I found http://www.howtogeek.com/126093/how-to-get-all-the-windows-8-editions-on-one-install-disk/ which was helpful for combining my Win8 installers, but I still need to figure out how to throw WinPE4 into the mix. For all the hacking I've done to my BCD and boot.wim, I can't believe I have never seen a boot options menu ever.

Answer (score 0):

easy2boot is a USB multiboot solution which can boot any number of UEFI FAT32 images. Use the MakePartImage tool to make each UEFI image and add it to the USB drive and boot.